# plotting with timedelta64 datatype in python

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like:

```
          duration     count    
0   -1 days +05:50:02   1    
1   -1 days +15:52:26   1   
2   -1 days +20:58:18   1
3   -1 days +23:16:12   1
4       00:00:00       418  
4819    08:42:00        23  
4820    08:47:52        23  
4821    09:45:13        1   
4822    10:19:36        1   
4823    10:57:37        1
```

where count referes to number of users who've used our product for given duration. I want to create a histogram that gives me a sense where my mean and outliers are.

datatypes are as follows:

```
duration timedelta64[ns]
count         int64
```

I've tried

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='duration', y='count')
```

which outputs

```
TypeError: Cannot cast scalar from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```